# Is there a memory difference between single and multiple db.put_async() in a transaction?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class A(db.Model):
  d = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

class B(db.Model):
  c = db.TextProperty()

def store(): #1
  db.put_async(A(key_name=x,parent=key) for x in x_list) #x_list: 5000
  db.put_async(B(c=y,parent=key) for y in y_list) #y_list: 2500*1KB

def store(): #2
  db.put_async([A(key_name=x,parent=key) for x in x_list]+
               [B(c=y,parent=key) for y in y_list])

db.run_in_transaction(store)
```

Which `store()` uses less memory?

Do the generators or separate RPCs make a difference? If I'm not mistaken `run_in_transaction()` basically collects puts and then transmits them at once anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making asynchronous calls, and not yielding the result, neither of them will do anything. If you use synchronous calls, option 1 will theoretically use less memory, but you should test this if it's important.

Comment: What do you mean with "neither of them will do anything"? The transaction blocks on the async puts.

Comment: @pdknsk You may be right - but you should still explicitly wait on them. In that case, no, it won't save any memory, because all the outstanding RPCs have to be held in memory until you wait on the results.